# Functional test symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, functional-programming, click

I want writing functional test with method click() but when i run my test the test return 
 : "Could not find the element "" (position 1) in the current DOM." what's the problem ?
help me please.

```
  <?php
  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../bootstrap/functional.php');

  $browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());

  $browser->get('/')->
  with('form')->begin()->
  click('bouton', array(
  'signin' => array(
  'username' => sfConfig::get('FUNC_ADMIN_USER'),
  'password' => sfConfig::get('FUNC_ADMIN_PASS'))))->
   end();
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Can you show some code?

Comment: Can you edit it into your question? It's easier to read there

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `with('form')->begin()->` (there is no `form` tester and you don't need it to simulate a click). You can `click` directly from the sfBrowser:

```
$browser->get('/')->
  click('bouton', array(
  'signin' => array(
  'username' => sfConfig::get('FUNC_ADMIN_USER'),
  'password' => sfConfig::get('FUNC_ADMIN_PASS'))));
```